# Sort factor using an other factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, s

I use this tutorial tu plot a heatmap using ggplot2

http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/

now I'd like to order the vertical factor using onother factor with the same length.

```
strains x1 x2 x3 origin
name     4 2  4   see
```

Does someone have any idea how does it work?

Thanks

Comment: For the nba dataset? Do you mean you want to sort the dataset by two factors?

Comment: I'd like to order the names for example on country names of the players. I have a similar data set with microorganisms and their origin and I want to sort the name on origin in the plot.

Comment: I don't see country name in that data set

Comment: I know but I have this in my data set.

Comment: So provide a reproducible example please

Answer (score 0):

If you have an extra column in *nba*, for instance `nba$country`, then you can adjust the ordering in the original by

```
nba$Name <- with(nba, reorder(Name, country))
```

If you have an alternative annotation that you want to order by, then you'll need to match that in.  For instance if you have a player-country data.frame (PC), then

```
nba$Name <- reorder(nba$Name, PC$country[match(nba$Name, PC$Name)])
```

Comment: How can I do this after the ddply function?

Comment: `nba.$Name <- reorder(nba.m$Name, nb$country[match(nba.m$Name, nb$Name)])` might do it, depending on where you've got _country_ defined